# Where are TorGuard VPN's settings stored?

Tags: files, vpn

I've installed TorGuard's VPN software for Ubuntu.

I tried activating one of their settings that minimises the program to the top bar. But this has prevented me from being able to open the application and view the window for it:

[image: TorGuard window]

It's supposed to minimise the window to the top bar, but it's not showing there:

[image: top bar on my Ubuntu PC]

And I know the app is running because it's showing as a process in the system monitor.

So now I can't use the app. I tried reinstalling it, but that didn't work. Therefore the settings must be stored somewhere, so if I delete that file it should reset it.

How can I find the settings for it?

Answer (score 0):

After contacting support the issue has been solved.

The config file is stored in `~/.config/VPNetworkLLC/TorGuard.conf`. Removing the file and restarting the app fixed the issue for me.